# Why does UIFileSharingEnabled + LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace behave like UISupportsDocumentBrowser?

Tags: ios, info.plist

If you want to expose the `Documents` folder of an iOS app in `iTunes`/`Music`, you need to set `UIFileSharingEnabled` in your `Info.plist` file.

If you want to expose the `Documents` folder in the `Files` app in iOS, you need to set `UISupportsDocumentBrowser` in your `Info.plist` file.

If you set both, you expose it both ways.

Finally, if you set `UISupportsDocumentBrowser` in your `Info.plist` file, you can also set  `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` in case you want to directly work with the original files, which means you have to explicitly coordinate file access. Without that flag you are working with copies, which is always safe without additional access coordination.

All of this makes totally sense to me but there is one thing that doesn't:

If both, `UIFileSharingEnabled` and `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` are set, the `Documents` folder is also exposed in the `Files` app, even though `UISupportsDocumentBrowser` is not set.

Why? That's not logical to me. It is officially documented that way but no explanation for that behavior is provided. Anyone knowing the technical aspect behind that? Is that some legacy behavior kept only for compatibility? Can anyone provide a meaningful explanation for this behavior? Or provide an example why this would be needed or is meaningful?